# Get number of unique pages visited each day

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there any way to get a number of unique pages visited each day from Google Analytics (API)?
I don't need the URLs themselves. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as as such, but you can query for ga:pagePath and ga:pageViews - since you need some metric for the request to work at all - and then just look at the count for the number of results (which is part of the API response). Since each visited page will be a distinct row in the response, the number of rows is the number of distinct urls.

One drawback is that there might be multiple rows per Url if they have parameters (e.g. /foo.html and /foo.htm?bar=1 will be two rows), unless you have removed parameters in your GA configuration or via filters. So you may have to process the results (loop over the url list, remove parameters from the urls, and do you own aggregation).

Comment: It's late here, but unless I understood his question wrong, wouldn't he just request ga:date along with ga:uniquePageviews? Of course the url parameter concern is very valid.

Comment: @XTOTHEL you are certainly right that he needs to query the date, or limit the query to a single day. But unique pageviews might still count a URL double (since this means unique per session, not unique per day over all sessions).

Comment: ah yes, you are correct. He's essentially looking for a row count. I need to go sleep.

Comment: Yep,  Eike is right, looks like row count might work. Thanks!